# Passing/injecting configuration into a PropertyValueConverter implementation

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'd like to be able to pass/inject runtime configuration parameters into a `PropertyValueConverter` and am struggling to find a clean way to go about it.

In this particular case, the property's a character stream (provider), and I'd like to be able to set a byte-length limit (per field) at runtime.

```kotlin
@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
@ValueConverter(CompactingInputStreamProviderConverter::class)
var fullText: (() -> InputStream)?
```

Would be nice if, e.g., the `PropertyValueConverter` could be a bean and I could just use Spring DI to get configuration in there, and if information about the field was exposed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [bean-aware PropertyValueConverterFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/4.1.6/reference/html/#mongo.property-converters.value-conversions) to enable DI in PropertyValueConverters:

```java
@Bean
public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions(ApplicationContext appContext) {
    return MongoCustomConversions.create(configurer -> {
        SimplePropertyValueConversions valueConversions = new SimplePropertyValueConversions();
        valueConversions.setConverterFactory(PropertyValueConverterFactory.beanFactoryAware(appContext));
        configurer.setPropertyValueConversions(valueConversions);
    });
}
```